# What does Index(encodedOffset:) do and how do I replace it?

Tags: swift, swift5

The code I have used throws the following error:

> 'init(encodedOffset:)' is deprecated: encodedOffset has been deprecated as most common usage is incorrect. Use String.Index(utf16Offset:in:) to achieve the same behavior.

What does this actually do and how can I replace it? Is there an easier way to achieve this string formatting?

```
extension String {
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String, replacmentCharacter: Character) -> String {
        var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
            guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
            let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
            let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
        }
        return pureNumber
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.Index(encodedOffset:)` converts an `Int` index to a `String.Index` index.

The suggested replacement is straightforward

```
let stringIndex = String.Index(utf16Offset: index, in: pattern)
```

But it's quite cumbersome to convert `Int` to `String.Index` forth and back.

This uses `String.Index` only

```
extension String {
    func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String, replacmentCharacter: Character) -> String {
        var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
        for index in pattern.indices {
            guard index < pureNumber.endIndex else { return pureNumber }
            let patternCharacter = pattern[index]
            guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
            pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: index)
        }
        return pureNumber
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there really no simpler way to regex a string, e.g. for a phone number?

Comment: It would be helpful if you describe in detail what the code is supposed to do. To *regex a string for a phone number* have a look at `NSDataDetector`